# High CPU with web streaming videos

Tags: graphics, video, cpu, video-streaming

Every time I start watching some video within a browser (both Firefox 40.0 and Chrome 44.0.2403.157 64-bit with no extensions) the CPU usage gets 100% (according to `htop` and system monitor) freezing the computer.

I've tried to change kernels (default 3.19, 4.0.9 and 4.1.6) and no changes.
I've tried to force hardware acceleration on both browsers and no changes.
Tried the live session USB-drive, always the same results.

Right now, I can't watch a single video on any site neither flash nor html5 without freezing. What's wrong? Am I the only one with this issues?

My PC: Samsung UltraBook series 5 with i5, HD4000 and 4Gb RAM running Ubuntu 14.04.3

I'm using mesa 10.3.2 and i915 drivers

I suspect some driver is not controlling temp properly because I have Windows 10 in the same machine and it works perfect there. With Ubuntu, while the pc is cool it plays normal but after some 10 min or so it start to get very hot and the CPU is very high and it freezes/lags.

CPU usage with Chrome:

[image]

CPU usage with Firefox:

[image]

the output of `grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo` is:

```
cpu MHz     : 2519.507
cpu MHz     : 2559.867
cpu MHz     : 2535.960
cpu MHz     : 2534.765
```

Edit:

Found what was wrong by accident: temperature!
I was just listening to music when all of a sudden my external hd just turned off by itself. When I touched it, my hand burned. Then I decided to mesure the temperature of my ultrabook with lm-sensors. At idle state temp was 73ºc. When watching videos it was 101ºc. So I turned it off, waited it cool down and turned on again with a fan at max speed in front. Done! My streaming videos are normal again, no lags, no freezes... temps now are max 89ºc and I can run multiples videos simultaneously.

Thank you all for the support!!!

Edit 2:

Also found out that enabling intel_pstate ([tutorial here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html)) helps prevents cpu overheating! This should come enabled by default in ubuntu imho.

Comment: Btw, you can post the image on imgur.com and then link it here.

Comment: What are the drivers in use? Have you tried by "downclocking" the CPU?

Comment: Under these loads, and when it lags, what are your CPU frequencies? Do `grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: I was looking for drastic thermal throttling of the CPU frequencies, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Yes, you probably need some sort of thermal daemon like thermald or tlp.

Comment: Hey Doug, I already had thermald installed... I just installed tlp, rebooted and tried it again... and still freezing... I guess I'll have to stick to windows to watch stream video :(

Comment: I had something similar happen in Windows. Video in browser would cause laptop to get very hot and fan would go crazy. It turned out that the ATI Catalyst software for my video card had a bunch of video processing options enabled by default, and disabling all of them reduced laptop heat immensely. Maybe you have something similar installed?

Comment: user5071535 i have intel hd4000 as gpu and I use default ubuntus driver... don't even know if it is possible to change any video setting at all.

Comment: For the most part the intel_pstate driver is enabled by default. Some changes to the driver are in the process of being backported to earlier kernels, and so perhaps it will become enabled by default for them. [Example](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1188647). Note also that many people have had issues with the intel_pstate driver, and they disable it.